# font roboto doesn't work when using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

I'm using in my website roboto font family with bootstrap-4 roboto font doesn't working. It's working this case: I am write like this `"font-family:"roboto-bold";` It's not working this case when I write with `"sans-serif"` font `"font-family: 'roboto-bold',sans-serif;"`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');


@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto-bold',sans-serif;
    src: url('./fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff') format('woff2'),
    url('./fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
  
} 
   
body {
    font-family: 'roboto-bold',sans-serif;
}
  
h2 {
    /* font-family: 'Roboto'; */
    font-family: 'roboto-bold',sans-serif;
    font-size: 47;
    color: red;
}

.tab-title{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'roboto-bold',sans-serif ;
    color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Doora Invoice</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demostyle.css">

</head>
<body>
  <main>
   <h2>hello</h2>
   <h3 class="tab-title"> overview</h3>
   <p>Hello</p>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can it be an issue of your `unicode-range` defintion? I googled `5ff` and my first result said, this is no valid unicode character: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5FF/index.htm Can you try without the definition of `unicode-range`?

Comment: yes i try without  "unicode-range" but still result are same

Answer (score 0):

see this if you want to change **weight** in font you have to specify in & select from google fonts family.and want to change font family name visit this [link](https://css-tricks.com/dont-just-copy-the-font-face-out-of-google-fonts-urls/)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

/*@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+000-5FF;
  
} */
   
body {
   font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}
  
h2 {
    /* font-family: 'Roboto'; */
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 47;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.tab-title{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    color: aqua;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Doora Invoice</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demostyle.css">




</head>
<body>
  <main>
   <h2>hello</h2>
   <h3 class="tab-title"> overview</h3>
   <p>Hello</p>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's working but one issues there when hard refresh first take system default font. in a second take font family font

Comment: you have to use preload in fonts visit this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload

Comment: also use preload in font